# How can I add a new user in UberSVN?

Tags: svn, ubersvn

How can I create a new account (username & password) in UberSVN (WANdisco)?

My SVN client and my SVN server are running on Windows machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where is the SVN folder on the server?

Let's suppose that all you know is an URL (because you are just a client) - E.g.: `my-host:9870` (replace the host and the port with your values).

1. Connect to `my-host` using **Remote Desktop Connection**
2. Open a **cmd** and type:

   ```
   echo off & (for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr 9870') do tasklist /FI "PID eq %a") & echo on
   ```

   You will get an output like this:

   ```
   Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
   ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
   httpd.exe                      405                            0        488 K
   ```

   So, based on your **port** number, you managed to see the process **image name** and **PID**.
3. Based on the **image name** or on the port, you can find the **path** of the **executable** file.

   E.g.:

   ```
   WMIC PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid | findstr httpd.exe
   ```

   You can also use PowerShell for this.

   One of the **output** lines:

   ```
   httpd.exe             "C:\Program Files\WANdisco\uberSVN\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
   ```

   So, you found the SVN folder location: `C:\Program Files\WANdisco\uberSVN\`.

---

#### How can I create a new user?

1. Open a **cmd** and change the path to: `C:\Program Files\WANdisco\uberSVN\bin`.
2. Type:

   ```
   htpasswd.exe -nb newuser newpassword
   ```

   where `newuser` and `newpassword` will be replaced with the values you want.

   Possible **output**:

   ```
   newuser:$apr1$Zyy11URO$nipJKOkb45Z8KaTInv32o1
   ```

   If you need some advanced options, just type `htpasswd.exe` to see what you can do with this executable.
3. Using explorer, go to `C:\Program Files\WANdisco\uberSVN\conf` and identify the files: **svn.authz** and **svn.passwd**.
4. Open **svn.authz** and add the new user.

   There is a line like this:

   ```
   RW__Everyone = user1, user2, user3
   ```

   Just change it to:

   ```
   RW__Everyone = user1, user2, user3, newuser
   ```
5. Open **svn.passwd** and add the output from point 2 as a new line at the end of the file:

   ```
   newuser:$apr1$Zyy11URO$nipJKOkb45Z8KaTInv32o1
   ```
6. Now it works without a server restart. You can test it from the client side (browser, Tortoise SVN, etc.).